# Motor failure detection and compensation in quadcopter

Tags: flight-simulator

I need to perform some analysis on motor failure detection and compensation in quadcopter. I have been using PX4+Gazebo for 3 months and recently found that it does not include motor failure detection logic. Are there any suggestions for a simulator that implements motor failure detection? I am looking for a software that can work with Ubuntu 18.04 or Windows 10.

Recommendations for software of any price are welcome.

Any insights would be very appreciated!

Comment: Welcome Heba!  Interesting question.  On which operating system(s) should the software run?  Do you have a price range in mind, or are you looking only for recommendations for gratis software?  If you can update your question with these details, it will help our community help you.  Again, welcome to Software Recommendations SE!

Comment: Thanks for your replay! Updated the question.
For the price, I am looking for all options including the gratis software.

Comment: You're welcome! I updated your question to include the price details.  I hope you find a good answer... or two!